# How do I get the dash to open on the application scope rather than the home scope

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, applications-lens

I want to be able to do this by clicking on the dash icon in the launcher rather than using some kind of key combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can already do it with 2 clicks:

- Right-click on the dash icon to open a context menu.
- Left-click "Applications".

Or with one click-and-drag:

- Right-click on the dash icon and hold the mouse button down to open a context menu.
- Move the mouse over the "Applications" option and release the right mouse button there.

Comment: Please don't thank ByteCommander!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  **;-)**